# Azure AD Authentication and https://login.microsoftonline.com whitelisting

Tags: azure, authentication, azure-active-directory

I have an App that is doing certificate based azure AD authentication before it can consume an azure app service to connect to azure database. This app is supposed to run on restricted devices where we need to whitelist all IPs to allow any traffic. I was able to successfully acquire static IP for azure app service. But for azure ad authentication, it goes to https://login.microsoftonline.com with appending tenant to it to acquire access token and this URL is never going to have any static IP.

Also, we can not whitelist just the hostname in the device. It needs to be IP with hostname.

We can not compromise the security so we need to have authentication but we can not proceed with AAD authentication as the authority would never have static IP.

We are doing certificate based authentication because we don't want to show any prompt and it should be a silent authentication.

Is there any other way to do AAD authentication silently which would not require to go to https://login.microsoftonline.com or any way to acquire static IP for this one?

Please suggest.

Comment: Absolutely  you cannot acquire  a static IP for the Auzre AD authorization endpoint. I think you can understand why.  It's for security ,loadbalancing and etc.

Comment: @WayneYang-MSFT,  Is there any way to achieve AAD authentication without going to MS authority?

Comment: There is no way to achieve that.

Comment: The MS authority (login.microsoftonline.com) is the site that validates the credentials in Azure AD. Without that, you wouldn't be using Azure AD. - Could you use a proxy server on a fixed IP, and setup the proxy server to only allow communication with the necessary hostnames? (It would have to do MITM decryption of the https traffic, though).